# num_rows are showing the expected answer?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

After creating the partition and added rows to the table in oracle. NUM_ROWS are not showing the expected answer?

```
 SQL>  SELECT num_rows, partition_name,table_name FROM DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS
       WHERE table_name='AUDITS';`

  NUM_ROWS PARTITION_NAME                 TABLE_NAME
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
           P2                             AUDITS
           P3                             AUDITS

SQL> SELECT count(*) FROM audits;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        98

SQL>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_2117.htm#REFRN20286) for `ALL_TABLES`, you will see this note

> Note:
>   Columns marked with an asterisk (*) are populated only if you collect statistics on the table with the `DBMS_STATS` package.

and further down,

> `NUM_ROWS*`

There is no such note for `DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS`, but I think it should be the same.